# Records[i] is Undefined on TreePanel

Tags: extjs, treepanel

I use treePanel with JSON. 
My JSON is here : [JSON](http://pastebin.com/b7UttwAh)

I don't understand why , i have this error message : " **Records[i] is undefined** "
My JSON is valid !

need help,

Thanks :)

Comment: Solution : 
Not same ID for each data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided much information on how you are using this JSON file but by the sounds of it you are trying to access an element which does not exist. Are you using a loop statement to increment through each element in your JSON file?

Maybe this loop is iterating past the number of elements that you have and this is why the error is occurring. If I were to take a guess I would say it is because the application is trying to parse the first "node" in your JSON file as a child and so it thinks there are 4 elements to loop through. Where as you really only have 3.

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: I solved my problem ! 
the problem is when each data has same id ! 
Thanks for you answers